# How to have label show up at the very bottom of the bar graph? APEX ORACLE

Tags: oracle-apex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjQW4.png)super simple question yet can't find the answer anywhere... How do I have the label of this one that I circled show up at the bottom of the bar graph?

Have tried all the different label options but none of the positions work.

Tried all different label positions.